# Simple OLS on Excel shows wrong R^2 value?

Tags: regression, r-squared, excel

I'm trying to make an OLS regression on Excel on those 2 values :

```
Y  X 
4  2 
5  3
```

According to wikipedia definition, R^2 = SSR/SST

Here if you compute the regression without intercept, you get B1 = 1.77, B0 = 0. So the predicted Y are :

```
 yPredicted[0] = 2 * B1 = 3.53
 yPredicted[1] = 3 * B1 = 5.30
```

The residual (y - yPredicted) are 0.462 and -0.307, so the sum of the squared residuals (called "SSR" or "SSE") is finally : 0.3076.

The sum of total square is, still according to definition, the sum of (y_i - avg(y))^2. In our case, it's 0.5^2 + 0.5^2 = 0.5

Finally, I get R^2 = 0.3076/0.5 = 0.6152

In this case though, it looks like Excel have a R^2 of 0,99249531, which is completely different. Do you know why R^2 of Excel is not the R^2 of what's been defined everywhere else on the Internet ? What version of R^2 should I use ? I'm really confused

Comment: I think this is really a duplicate, but I can't quickly find one.

Answer (score 4):

Two distinct points in the plane -- differing in $y$ and $x$ -- define a tilted straight line unambiguously. In your case, the line is $y = 1x + 2$, a regression fit should be perfect, and $R^2$ should be $1$. Otherwise put, the correlation between $y$ and $x$ for that example is necessarily $1$ and so is $R^2$.

Otherwise the game you're playing is fitting the regression without an intercept, which in no sense is the standard or even default definition of regression. But it is agreed to be a known variant.

It does not seem a good idea for this example, but playing along....

I didn't try to follow your calculations, but the main issue is this. When asked to fit without an intercept, most software I know changes the definition of $R^2$ to, in effect, answering how much better the regression prediction is than zero, rather than how much better the regression prediction is than the mean of $y$. My own favourite software matches the Excel result in the sense that it gives $ .9924953095684803$ as a result for $R^2$.

This different definition has surprised many people and in several cases was evidently not what they expected.

Comment: I'm actually trying to fit a timeSeries into a AR(1) model, by extracting kappa and sigma from : y_t = kappa * y_{t-1} + sigma * epsilon (= white noise).  If you consider sigma * epsilon being the residual of the regression, then there is no "variable" in the model to be caught by any intercept, that's why i'm not using it :)

Comment: So your real question is quite different.